# Android Search icon not showing up on Action Bar

Tags: android, xml, search, android-actionbar

I was following this tutorial on Android when i came across a problem. As mentioned in topic my search icon isn't showing up on the action bar.
I had problem with that step.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html
I think i have done everything the same but still nothing shows up.
I've seen other people having similar problem but their answers didn't work for me.

The worst thing is unlike others people problems related to search icon not showing up, mine isn't even showing up on overflow while theirs is. Maybe it can guide someone to what's my issue.

main_activity_actions.xml code below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

activity.main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.pawel.androidapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here.
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void openSearch() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Search pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void openSettings() {
        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));       
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

androidapp manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pawel.androidapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pawel.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pawel.androidapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Maybe its silly question but did you copy search icon to your drawable folder? https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks for you response, yes I've copied all of them to drawable folders.(by all of them i mean different sizes)

Comment: What about changing app:showAsAction to android:showAsAction.

Comment: @TheGalax please post your manifest!

Comment: Thanks for all the responses @mmlooloo I've added my androidapp manifest.

Comment: @daredesm I've tried that before

Comment: I see that you're using the support variant for ActionBar as your menu resource uses a custom defined `app` namespace. Does your device have a menu button? If so, what happens when you press it?

Comment: Bump.  Any solutions to this?  Have the exact same issue with same fix attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  You're using minSdkVersion="11" which is when the ActionBar APIs were defined.  (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

The line I had wrong was:
  **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"**

I had looked at the development tutorials which are illustrating use of the Support Library and my line looked the same as yours.  I changed it to this: 
  **android:showAsAction="ifRoom"**

and it worked.  Use the "android" namespace instead of the "app" namespace. 
(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, I got the answer after exchanging below 3 "android" to "app":

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="100" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="101" />
</menu>
```

Comment: please change the "always" to "never"

Answer (score 1):

I had the ditto problem and i did not change anything in the code as others suggest above. I had downloaded the Action Pack icons from Android URL "http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack" and this has two folders named "Core Icons" and "Action Bar Icons". I used the icon **ic_action_search** from within the "Core Icons" folder and that caused the problem. I replaced the icon at "drawable" folder with the one from "Action Bar Icons/Holo Dark" and it was working the way intended. That was a moment of relief for a android developer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely down to

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

You're basically saying only show the icon if there is room available to show it. So try :

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html for more.

Edit :

Sorry, I've just noticed that you're using the namespace http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto for this attribute.

Does it work if you change it to :

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

from your item.

Comment: I've added to both, main.xml and main_activity_actions.xml, and nothing. Btw just curious their code is the same in my project, should it be like that or did i screw something up?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my project and I found that the issue was in the Manifest file.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

Change it to:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```